# Convert value to type Json.net

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android, json.net

I using Json.NET to store some preferences of my app, but when I try to get the values from file, I recive this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   "{"Kepp_Active":1,"Speech_Words":0}" to type 'MyTestApp.Configs'.
>   Path '', line 1, position 40.

My Code:

```
string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var configJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configs>(jsonContent,
          new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
          });
```

My Configs class:

```
public class Configs
{
    [JsonProperty("Kepp_Active")]
    public int KeepActive;

    [JsonProperty("Speech_Words")]
    public int Speech;
}
```

Edit 1:

My Configs class:

```
public class Configs
{
    [JsonProperty("Keep_Active")]
    public int KeepActive;

    [JsonProperty("Speech_Words")]
    public int Speech;
}
```

Error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   "{"Keep_Active":1,"Speech_Words":0}" to type 'Placar_Fodinha.Configs'.
>   Path '', line 1, position 40

Edit 2:

Store code:

```
Configs cfg = new Configs();
cfg.Speech = 0;
cfg.KeepActive = 1;
string configsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cfg);                
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(filePath))
{
   JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
   serializer.Serialize(file, configsJson);
}
```

.

Comment: What does `Configs` look like?

Comment: Configs Added now.

Comment: You code exactly as posted works.

Comment: @msitt But here keeps the error, the Json is right?

Comment: OK...can you show what `jsonContent` is? I used `"{\"Kepp_Active\":1,\"Speech_Words\":0}"`.

Comment: @msitt Yes, this is the `jsonContent`. `"{\"Kepp_Active\":1,\"Speech_Words\":0}"`

Comment: @msitt I have tested the code, with the same result like you. It works fine.

Comment: I think it's not the solution, but have you tried to replace the "File.ReadAllText" with "{\"Kepp_Active\":1,\"Speech_Words\":0}" ? With that, you make sure, whether the "File.Read" is the problem!?

Comment: @SeanStayn I tried now, replacing `"File.ReadAllText"` to `"{\"Kepp_Active\":1,\"Speech_Words\":0}"` works.

Comment: Hm.. are you sure, that the content of "jsonContent" really  "{\"Kepp_Active\":1,\"Speech_Words\":0}" is? In most cases there are additionally signs like "\n" in the strings, readed from file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last update: You serialize "cfg" twice.

First at:

```
string configsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cfg);
```

Second at:

```
serializer.Serialize(file, configsJson);
```

This is the reason, why the saved JSON string looks like:

> "\"{\\"KeepActive\\":1,\\"SpeechWords\\":0}\""

If you delete this line:

```
string configsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cfg);
```

and add the "cfg" to the other line:

serializer.Serialize(file, cfg);

The response will be saved in your file like:

> "{\"KeepActive\":1,\"SpeechWords\":0}"

And you should be able to de-serialize it.

Your code to safe the JSON string should look like this:

```
Configs cfg = new Configs();

cfg.Speech = 0;
cfg.KeepActive = 1;

using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("myTestFile.txt"))
{

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, cfg);
}
```

**Images:**

With your code:

[image]

With the new code:

[image]

Comment: The error keeps Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"Keep_Active":1,"Speech_Words":0}" to type 'MyTestApp.Configs'. Path '', line 1, position 40.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have used another way to store and to read the json. Perhaps it works for you. P.S.: You can see, that the "jsonContent" contains "\n", but it's not a problem.

Comment: I added an breakpoint at `string jsonContetn = File.ReadAllText(filePath);` and the retrived string is `"\"{\\\"KeepActive\\\":1,\\\"SpeechWords\\\":0}\""` with three \, I think it is the cause of troubles.

Comment: Yes, of course and the \" at the beginning and the end. Can you show, how you store the JSON string to file?

Comment: Of course, I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: I think, I have founded the issue. You serialize "cfg" to "configsJson" and after that you serialize "configsJson" again (twice). Please try this: serializer.Serialize(file, cfg);

Comment: I could reproduce your error and I have updated my answer with the solution. I hope it will help you.